# On account created from Google/Facebook auth, write uid to 'Users/'

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

When a new account is created using Google auth/ Facebook auth, I want to write their uid to a tree called `Users/`.

How should I go about this?

```
firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(function(result) {
    if (result.credential) {

    }
    // The signed-in user info.
    var user = result.user;
    // Maybe something like this?
    if (result.newUser) {
        // Write to database
    }
    }).catch(function(error) {
        // Handle Errors here.
 });
```

Thanks!

Comment: @Searching I don't want this to call each time someone logs in if they are not a new user because there will be more data associated later with their uid

Comment: So are intending to save/update user data with userid as the key of the document ?

Comment: @Searching I'm wanting to save uid when a new user is authenticated via google

Comment: Think about this for a moment: what determines if someone is a new user in this scenario? Likely the answer is that you consider them new when there is no record for them in the database yet. That means you'll need to read the user's record to determine if you should write it. To detect if a record exists, see http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D+detect+if+node+exists

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Much thanks